# Why is "throw" a restricted production for automatic semicolon insertion?

Tags: javascript, grammar

Part of JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion algorithm is so-called "restricted productions". These are syntactical forms which forbid a newline character from occurring at a certain point. To quote the ECMAScript 2015 specification:

> If the phrase “[no *LineTerminator* here]” appears in the right-hand side of a production of the syntactic grammar, it indicates that the production is a *restricted production*: it may not be used if a *LineTerminator* occurs in the input stream at the indicated position.

There are 10 restricted productions in the ECMAScript 2015 specification:

- *PostfixExpression*<sub>[Yield]</sub> **:** *LeftHandSideExpression*<sub>[?Yield]</sub> [no *LineTerminator* here] `++`
- *PostfixExpression*<sub>[Yield]</sub> **:** *LeftHandSideExpression*<sub>[?Yield]</sub> [no *LineTerminator* here] `--`
- *ContinueStatement*<sub>[Yield]</sub> **:** `continue` [no *LineTerminator* here] *LabelIdentifier*<sub>[?Yield]</sub> `;`
- *BreakStatement*<sub>[Yield]</sub> **:** `break` [no *LineTerminator* here] *LabelIdentifier*<sub>[?Yield]</sub> `;`
- *ReturnStatement*<sub>[Yield]</sub> **:** `return` [no *LineTerminator* here] *Expression* `;`
- *ReturnStatement*<sub>[Yield]</sub> **:** `return` [no *LineTerminator* here] *Expression*<sub>[In, ?Yield]</sub> `;`
- *ThrowStatement*<sub>[Yield]</sub> **:** `throw` [no *LineTerminator* here] *Expression*<sub>[In, ?Yield]</sub> `;`
- *ArrowFunction*<sub>[In, Yield]</sub> **:** *ArrowParameters*<sub>[?Yield]</sub> [no *LineTerminator* here] `=>` *ConciseBody*<sub>[?In]</sub>
- *YieldExpression*<sub>[In]</sub> **:** `yield` [no *LineTerminator* here] `*` *AssignmentExpression*<sub>[?In, Yield]</sub>
- *YieldExpression*<sub>[In]</sub> **:** `yield` [no *LineTerminator* here] *AssignmentExpression*<sub>[?In, Yield]</sub>

Of these productions, I understand the choice to make most of them restricted. The production for *PostfixExpression* is restricted to prevent parsing ambiguity with *PrefixExpression*. *ContinueStatement*, *BreakStatement*, and *ReturnStatement* have restricted productions because there are corresponding productions where `break` and `continue` do not take labels and `return` does not take an expression. I can't say that I know enough about arrow functions or yield expressions to know why they are restricted, but I assume it is to prevent some sort of similar parsing ambiguity.

The production which I don't understand is *ThrowExpression*. As far as I can tell, there is no parsing ambiguity involved in using `throw` like there is when using `break`, `return`, and `continue`: after all, `throw;` is not valid JavaScript. I thought that it might be for historical reasons, but as far as I can tell `throw;` has never been allowed in any JavaScript specification.

The practical consequence of this is that much like with `return`, you can't put the expression being thrown on the next line, e.g. this is wrong:

```
throw
new Error("some error");
```

However, unlike `return`, this doesn't have different behavior than putting the `new Error()` on the same line. It's just a syntax error: Chrome reports it as

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal newline after throw

Is the production for *ThrowExpression* restricted just to maintain consistency with similar contstructs? Or is there some ambiguity I'm not seeing?

Comment: I think it means you can't do `throw **newline** "error";` it has to be on a single line, just like with `return **newline** "returned";` it would just return `undefined` because the value to be returned can't be on a new line? In most other cases, newlines doesn't matter in javascript.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, that's the consequence of it being a restricted production. The question I'm asking is why that's the case.

Comment: I think the answer is probably something like *"because the specification says it's so"*, the ECMA spec says that semicolons should be inserted *(the ASI rules)* after `return`, `throw` etc. and for that reason they can't be followed by a newline, as then the parser would be confused as to where the statement ends ?

Comment: @adeneo The ASI rules are defined in terms of restricted productions. If the production for `throw` was not defined to be restricted, then there would be (as far as I can tell)  no problem with putting the value to throw on a new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `throw` was added to the language in 1998 or so, there was a discussion about whether the throw statement required an expression or not. (The alternative would be that a `throw` without an expression rethrows the current exception object, as in [certain other languages](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw).)

I can't find any record of this discussion, or of the final resolution -- although we know what the resolution was -- but it is mentioned in the [TC39 meeting notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20000815212503/http://www2.hursley.ibm.com/tc39/tcn9802t.htm) for the meeting of February 19, 1998. I suppose that the intent of the restriction was to leave the syntactic space open in case someday the decision were changed.

Comment: Thank you @rici. Would you have any idea as to why [ArrowFunction](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ArrowFunction) was restricted? The reason given here is [future compatibility](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/why-is-no-line-break-is-needed-in-arrowfunction#content-1) with headless arrow functions. But I'm not sure I understand this reason. Why do we need ASI to kick in here: `var x = (y) \n => 5;` (SyntaxError due to illegal line break) but not here: `var x = y \n (m);` (parses as `var x = y(m);`)

Comment: @user51462: It's pretty clear that the restriction is to allow future compatibility, as stated in the proposal you cite. To be sure, less care was taken at the beginning, when JS's designers didn't have much idea how bad an idea it would be to permit function calls and subscript expressions to be broken over two lines. Silently unexpected parses are a huge cause of bugs; all the linters I know of attempt to warn you about inappropriately split expressions (and in many projects, the linters are mandatory). Unfortunately, backwards compatibility makes the original flaw hard to correct.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me @rici. That's exactly what I meant by my original question, i.e. why did they decide to restrict `ArrowFunction` but not `CallExpression`. Allowing a `CallExpression` to be split over multiple lines seems incommensurate with the whole purpose of ASI. Since I am new to the spec and programming in general, I wasn't sure of the reason, so thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 4):

We can only guess here *why* the language authors decided to make it so, but I'd say it's for consistency with `return`. Both `return ¶ value` and `throw ¶ value` are forbidden if you want to complete with the `value`. That there would be no ambiguity for `throw` anyway doesn't matter.

Comment: "We can only guess here why the language authors decided to make it so" - perhaps, but maybe this has been documented somewhere. Maybe in an early draft `throw;` was the same as `throw undefined;`, for example.

Comment: @WillKunkel - These questions pop up all the time, where the answer is just that noone really knows. Best case, maybe you could try asking Brendan Eich if he knows why it's like this. He has his own website, is on Twitter, Facebook, ESDiscuss etc.

Comment: @adeneo That could well be the case. It's not exactly critical that I find this out; I just thought it was interesting. If someone does know, it would be nice to have it documented here.

Comment: @adeneo And sometimes these questions get really interesting answers with citations from the experts.

Answer (score 2):

I think [adeneo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311318/why-is-throw-a-restricted-production-for-automatic-semicolon-insertion#comment64039456_38311318) is on the right track: like `return`, the operand to `throw` is typically a valid expression on its own. The problem with `return \n "valid on its own";` is one of the most common examples of ASI problems, so restricting `return` and any other statements taking a value like that is a reasonable safeguard.

Looking at the list, most of those are unary operators (or look just like one). They all follow the same general form, except for arrow functions. That form is a cause of ASI errors, so restricting the whole category is more predictable than just `return`.

Comment: The reason most of them are restricted is because you can have both, for example, `return;` and `return "hello";`. So if there's a newline in `return \n "hello"`, it could be ambiguous which form is intended. This is not the case for *ThrowExpression*: `throw;` is a syntax error.

Comment: It's also worth noting that not all unary operators are restricted productions. For example, `- \n 5;` is perfectly fine JavaScript, if a bit pointless.